# chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished not fired for all requests on page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome devtools extension which listens to `chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished` like

`chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(onRequestFinished);`

I've noticed that not all page requests get to my listener function, for example, when POSTing a request, only the preflight OPTIONS request triggers my onRequestFinished callback although the POST request is going out successfully with response 200 (I can see it in the network tab).

Any reason for this?

**UPDATE**
I just tried it on Canary and it works as expected, seems like a bug on chrome 61

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Check https://crbug.com for an existing report or submit a new one with a sample extension that exhibits the bug. Also try in another version of Chrome like a portable of 59 or a separate install of Chrome Canary.

Comment: I just tried it on Canary and it works as expected, seems like a bug on chrome 61